# How to find any decrement in the column?

Tags: sorting, unix, awk, bc

I am trying to find out the decrements in a column and if found then print the last highest value.

For example:

From `111` to `445` there is a continous increment in the column.But `333` is less then the number before it.

```
111 aaa  
112 aaa  
112 aaa  
113 sdf  
115 aaa  
222 ddd  
333 sss  
333 sss  
444 sss  
445 sss  
333 aaa<<<<<<this is less then the number above it (445)
```

If any such scenario is found then print `445 sss`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this, for example:

```
$ awk '{if (before>$1) {print before_line}} {before=$1; before_line=$0}' a
445 sss
```

What is it doing? Check the variable `before` and compare its value with the current. In case it is bigger, print the line.

It works for many cases as well:

```
$ cat a
111 aaa
112 aaa
112 aaa
113 sdf
115 aaa  <--- this
15 aaa
222 ddd
333 sss
333 sss
444 sss
445 sss  <--- this
333 aaa
$ awk '{if (before>$1) {print before_line}} {before=$1; before_line=$0}' a
115 aaa
445 sss
```

Comment: I just need line above the decremented value, for example "445 sss"

Answer (score 0):

Store each number in a single variable called prevNumber then when you come to print the next one do a check e.g. if (newNumber < prevNumber) print prevNumber;

dont really know what language you are using

Answer (score 0):

You can say:

```
awk '$1 > max {max=$1; maxline=$0}; END{ print maxline}' inputfile
```

For your input, it'd print:

```
445 sss
```